# Postgres native query not working while using in SpringBoot JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I am trying this query `select * from device_analytics where extract(year from comm_mnth) = 2021 and extract(month from comm_mnth) = 8 and comm_type = 'DEVICE'` in sql editor and it is returning data as expected. But when I trying the same query via JPA using native query its returning null, what is wrong here in JPA query.

```
@Query(value = "select * from device_analytics where extract(year from comm_mnth) =:year and extract(month from comm_mnth) =:month and comm_type =:commType", nativeQuery = true)
    DeviceAnalyticsEntity findDeviceAnlayticsEntity(@Param("month") int month, @Param("year") int year,
            @Param("commType") String commType);
```

// This returns null

```
analyticsRepoRo.findDeviceAnlayticsEntity(9, 2021,"DEVICE");
```

TIA